# How to enable word wrap of buttons in Slack Channel of Microsoft bot framework

Tags: botframework, slack, azure-bot-service

### Microsoft Bot Framework Version

4.9.2

### Issue

In Slack Channel Buttons with longer text are cut short instead of wordwrap.

### To Reproduce

Steps to reproduce the behavior:

1. Follow the steps mentioned here to connect a bot to Slack https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-channel-connect-slack?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=abs
2. Ensure to perform the optional step regarding configuring Interactive message with URL https://slack.botframework.com/api/Actions
3. Have your bot respond with buttons having 8 -10 words
4. The button text are not shown

### Expected behavior

The button text should wrap into next line (like msteams channel)

### Screenshots

[image]

I am aware of the option to format for slack using "ChannelData" , however i am wondering if this is somehow to be taken care by https://slack.botframework.com/api/Actions

Comment: I doubt if this can be done in Slack, I am checking with engineering team if this available and I will let you know.

Comment: @YutongTie-MSFT - Just trying to catch up if you have any updates from the engineering team.